# To Avoid Fluckring Of LEDs in Video Camera

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3, gif, led, pwm

LEDs are controlled through PWM. At 100 PWM, there is no flickering in the video. However, below 100 PWM, there is a flickering observed.
I want to ignore the Flucking in the video by giving any random value of PWM to the LEDs. the camera fps rate is 30fps

Comment: Using PWM to drive a LED is **fundamentally** making it flicker. Constant current driver would avoid this.